# Convert JSON-Encoded Text to an array

Tags: php, json

I have a string of text that is encoded in such a way:

```
 {"itemId":"17417362","type":"0","cclass":0,"value":"100","category":null,"image":{"url":"\/\/cdn.site.com\/insight.site.com\/COS20\/_Cache\/_ImageCache\/362\/17417362.gif","height":"100","width":"80"},"burstText":"","summary":"SAVE $1.00 ON TWO","brand":"Big \u00ae","link_text":"","link_url":"","activated":"2012-09-01T00:01:00","expiration":"2012-10-31T23:59:00","isuff":"362\/17417362.gif","imagePrefix":null,"details":"when you buy TWO BOXES: Original \u00ae ...","catid":"531","catdesc":"Ready to Eat","slot":"-415","prodinfo":"when you buy TWO BOXES any flavor: Original \u00ae \u2022 \u00ae \u202 \u00ae...","cpnuse":"1","printed":null,"actiontaken":null,"printCount":null,"onCard":null,"sid":"11079187","fid":"06338174","videoURL":"","catlevel1":"107","catlevel2":"399","catlevel3":"531","catdesc1":"Foods","catdesc2":"Breakfast","catdesc3":"Ready to Eat","restricted":0},"17557036":
```

I've tried json_decode on this string but it fails. I think this is due to the special characters and general format. How can I clean this up for decode?

Comment: Your text is either invalid or incomplete.  It ends suddenly midstream with `"17557036":'

Comment: May be you have text limits, that cuts some of your JSON. If you get it from DB, you should use big column to store it.

Comment: Could I use regex to remove this remainder?

Comment: Removed text after ,
$posoflastcomma = strrpos($myText,',');  //Position of last comma
$newText = substr_replace($myText, " ", $posoflastcomma);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters, your string terminates abruptly: `"17557036":` is the last of it - thus, not well-formed JSON.

Comment: After removing everything after the last } json_decod worked perfectly. Thanks!